# If statement assistance for powershell beginner

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-4.0

Right now I have a powershell script that launches Lync and then Skype for business after test-path to see if it exists. I'm trying to add the below into a larger if statement so it will run the lync portion and then only run the office communicator portion if lync doesn't exist.  I've tried this a few different ways and failed. Can anyone assist?

```
if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe'){

Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe'
} Else {
write-host "Lync is not installed"}


if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator'){

Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator\communicator.exe'
} Else {
write-host "Communicator is not installed"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest your second IF inside the ELSE of the first one, like this:

```
if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe')
{
    Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe'
}
Else
{
   write-host "Lync is not installed"
   if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator')
   {
        Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator\communicator.exe'
   }
   Else 
   {
           write-host "Communicator is not installed"}
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works great. Can you explain to me why the below did not work by any chance? Please ignore the marks to comment everything out.

##if (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe'){

##Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\office15\lync.exe'
##} Else {
##write-host "Lync is not installed"}



##elseif (Test-Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator'){

##Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator\communicator.exe'
##} Else {
##write-host "Communicator is not installed"}

Comment: You'd get more assistance if you post your second question as a new question.